# Getting the IP address of a VM created via Proxmox

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, proxmox

I've inherited a server which is using proxmox for the virtualisation, I'd like to know what is the IP address of a VM.
I've managed to get the list of VMs available on the server by using `qm list`:

```
  VMID NAME       STATUS     MEM(MB)    BOOTDISK(GB) PID
 99001 web-dev1   running    2048              50.00 1234
 99002 web-dev2   running    2048              50.00 2345
 99003 web-dev3   running    2048              50.00 3456
 99004 web-dev4   running    2048              50.00 4567
```

How can I know, without accessing directly and running a command in it, the IP address associated with each VM?

Thank you,

Fabio

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the fastest way would be using arp cache :

```
arp -a
```

Then look at the MAC address of each VM :

```
qm config VMID
```

Comment: To create a list of all proxmox configs in file: qm list | awk '{{print $1}}' | tail -n +2 | xargs -I{} qm config {} | tee /tmp/qm.configs

Answer (score 4):

Here it is guys:

Since this came up while I was searching the problem, I would like to post the following:

1 - Make sure qemu-ga is updated in the guest : https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/ (Keep this link around you)

2 - SSH into your Host run : qm guest cmd vmid network-get-interfaces

Regards,

Alvaro Lamadrid

Answer (score 1):

```
ip=*your-ip-address*; grep -ri $(arp -a | grep $ip | awk '{print $4}') /etc/pve/
```

[image: output]

Explanation:

- `ip=your-ip-address;` -- assign the variable the IP address of interest
- `grep -ri` -- perform a recursive (`-p` option) case-insensitive search (`-i` option) in the `/etc/pve` directory
- `$()` -- return the output of commands enclosed in parentheses
- `arp -a` -- shows active ip-addresses and their MAC-addresses, option `-a` display (all) hosts in alternative (BSD) style
- `|` -- the pipeline symbol redirects utility output
- `grep $ip` -- looks for a line that mentions the address from the `$ip` variable
- `awk '{print $4}'` -- parses output from grep utilities

Comment: Okay, I'll explain.
`ip=your-ip-address;` -- assign the variable the IP address of interest;
`grep -ri` -- perform a recursive (-p option) case-insensitive search (-i option) in the `/etc/pve` directory;
`$()` -- return the output of commands enclosed in parentheses;
`arp -a` -- shows active ip-addresses and their MAC-addresses, option -a display (all) hosts in alternative (BSD) style;
`"|"` -- the pipeline symbol redirects utility output;
`grep $ip` -- looks for a line that mentions the address from the $ip variable;
`awk '{print $4}'` -- parses output from grep utilities.

Comment: Please [edit] to do the explaining in your answer post itself.